# Is there a way to read a text file and send it as the body of an email using R. I want to send the email using an outlook account

Tags: r, outlook, sendmailr

I know that this is possible with python. However, I want to know if there is a way to do this with R as well. 
Code snippets will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are diverse ways, see [this overview for example](https://blog.mailtrap.io/r-send-email/).
SMTP settings for Outlook and Office365 can be [found here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040).

Fill your credentials in the following snippet and it should work straight away:

```
install.packages("remotes")
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("datawookie/emayili")

install.packages("magrittr")

library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr)  
library(emayili)

msg <- envelope() %>%
  from("you@email.net") %>%
  to("me@outlook.com") %>%
  subject("Test email subject") %>%
  attachment("./yourFile.txt") %>%
  text("Test email body")

smtp <- server(host = "smtp.office365.com",
           port = 587,
           username = "username",
           password = "password")

smtp(msg, verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you please mark it as answered so others can benefit.